# How can I put multiple actors on a Button?

Tags: libgdx

I like to have an Button with a Text and some Pictures in it.

Is there something out of the box to that ?

I mean I would like to add a Table into a button, so I could add anything I need to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Button` extends `Table` so you can treat it just like a normal **libGDX** `Table` and add any `Actor`s you want to it.